# Optimistic locking vs separate lock store for background workers

Tags: mysql, message-queue, distributed-computing, rdbms

I need to compute the value of a row R on a table based on rows queried on another table B.
I need to do it in a queue worker because the computation of the value can be slow. A message is queued everytime B change.

If the two workers start the computation of row R almost at the same time, and the data on table B changed the final value of row R may be wrong. I just want the final value to be the right, I don't care if I jump a computation.

To do that I can :

- Do optimistic lock on row R. Before the computation I read the version of R and when I update I do `where version = ?`. It ensures there are an independent computations n times if table B change n times (not 100% sure about that ^^). And I re-queue if a transaction fails.
- Store a lock in `etcd` or something like this, the advantage is to avoid useless computations... And I re-queue if the row is locked
- Use a FIFO queue (but I would like to avoid that)
- maybe something else?

What do you think is the best option?

Comment: It depends on the odds that values in B change during a computation, and how much you value stale data in R. At one extreme (low rate of change in B, stale value worthless) you'd choose a very different method than at the other (high rate of change in B, recent values of R could be used). Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Tibo Each value on table B is associated with an user. Most of the time the value only change when this user does something. And the row R is based on a custom formula for this user. So most of the time the computation is done before the user do something else causing table B to change.

But sometimes row in B are massively updated. So everything can change very quickly.

The only thing I care about row R is that, at the end, the value is correct. It's better if R get a new value for most change in B but I don't care if it jumps values

Answer (score 1):

> A message is queued everytime B change.

Arrange so that the message is monotonically versioned (e.g. after the first message is assigned `generation: 1`, the next message can only use a greater number).

Arrange so that a message is only consumed by at most one worker.

Workers can disappear in the middle of computation, so a retry mechanism is needed: periodically inject dummy messages from a watchdog thread/threads.

> I don't care if I jump a computation.

How worker commits its work:

- wait to acquire mutex named `TableR`
- ensure their result is newer than the latest stored result (> `generation`)
- store their result (or drop it altogether if outdated)
- release mutex `TableR`

Workers can disappear when holding a mutex - your mutex implementation must be smart enough to detect that (e.g. mutex backed by keepalives). Let's say  `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is a simplistic but good-enough implementation of such mutex.

This works for both distributed and local workers.

---

Optional, but handy: arrange for workers to drop computation quickly as soon as it becomes useless.

> Most of the time the computation is done before [the next message about B arrives]

This is a crucial assumption. For example if instead you expect 1 message per second and a computation needs 2 seconds you cannot do what follows below.

Arrange a pub/sub, which sends all the requests to all the workers. (This is an optional addition to the message queue above, not a replacement of it!) A worker drops ongoing computation if it receives a request with a greater `generation`.

Alternatively to a pub/sub, keep at most one worker at any time, just get it restarted after it disappears. It seems that multiple workers are not strictly required for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Optimistic lock should be the default approach although using different isolation levels (serialisable, repeatable reads, read committed, read uncommitted) for database transaction or locking reads (`select ... for update`, `select ... for share`) may represent a viable solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).